# Function getting garbage value

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
   void clearKeyboard(void)
   {
       while (getchar() != '\n')   ; // empty execution code block on purpose
   }
   int yes(void)
   {

       char a,b;
       printf("<Please enter a character>: ");
       scanf("%c%c", &a,&b);

       while ((a !='Y' && a !='y' && a !='N' && a!='n') || (b!='\n'))
       { 
          if (b!='\n') ungetc(b, stdin),scanf("%*[^\n]%c", &b);
          a='n',b='\n';
          clearKeyboard();
          printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
          scanf("%c%c", &a,&b);

        }
        if (a =='Y' || a=='y')
        {
            printf("Contact Management System: terminated\n");
            return 1;

        }
        else 
        {
            if (a =='N' || a=='n')
            ContactManagerSystem();
            return 0;
        }

   }

   int menu(void)

   {
       int i;
       printf("0. Exit\n\nSelect an option:> ");
       scanf("%d", &i);
       while (i<0 || i>6)
       {
           printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between 0 and 6>: ");
           scanf("%d", &i);
       }
       return i;
   }

   void ContactManagerSystem(void)

   {
     int i=menu();

      switch(i)
      {
         case 0 :
          printf("Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o: ");
          yes();


       }

   }
   int main(void)
   {
       ContactManagerSystem();
   }







So my "yes" function is working fine on it's own but when I call it within
```

ContactManagerSystem() case 0 It's going crazy for some reason 
    The "yes" function is actually a validation check function I need the user 
    to enter "yes" or "no" as in 'Y''y''N' or 'n'
    Wait for the user to enter “Y”, ”y”, “N” or “n” (for Yes or No).
    If the user replies Yes (“Y”,”y”), it will end the program displaying the 
    following message:

> Contact Management System: terminated< (followed by a newline)
>       Otherwise, if the user entered No (“N”,”n”), the application continues to 
>       display the menu.

Comment: Use parentheses.  If `a` is set to `'y'` (and followed by the return key), then it is not equal to `'Y'` or `'n'` or `'N'`, so the `||` conditions evaluate to true.  If you actually typed `yes`, you'd have a different problem.  And indicating EOF leads to reprehensible behaviour.

Comment: `a != X || a != Y` (and `X != Y`) is always true.

Comment: You don't need `clearKeyboard`.

Comment: But it's still not working when I call it within ContactManagerSystem

Comment: Don't call `ContactManagerSystem` from `yes`. Don't change your question again.

Comment: but that's the requirement for my assignment

Answer (score 2):

I think  you need to rethink your use of `&&` and `||`, and use parentheses.  This code also takes care of EOF and words (like "yes") being typed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a, b;
    printf("<Please enter a character>: ");
    if (scanf("%c%c", &a, &b) == 2)
    {
        while ((a != 'Y' && a != 'y' && a != 'N' && a != 'n') || b != '\n')
        {
            printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
            if (b != '\n')
            {
                int c;
                while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                    ;
            }
            if (scanf("%c%c", &a, &b) != 2)
                break;
        }
        if (a == 'Y' || a == 'y')
        {
            printf("Got yes!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (a == 'N' || a == 'n')
        {
            printf("Got no!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Got EOF\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If the letter in `a` is neither `'Y'` nor `'y'` nor `'N'` nor `'n'` or if the value in `b` is not a newline, report problems, gobble up any stray characters up to the newline (or EOF), and then resume.  Report status via printing as well as exit status.

Example runs:

```
$ ./scan13; echo $?
<Please enter a character>: yes
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: no
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: pdq
*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: y
Got yes!
1
$ scan13; echo $?
<Please enter a character>: n
Got no!
0
$ ./scan13; echo $?
<Please enter a character>: Got EOF
0
$
```

As noted in the comments below, one of the problems with `scanf()` is making sure the behaviour on error is as intended.  It is often easier to read a whole line into a buffer using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), and then parse the data with [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Comment: I think you meant to compare against `'\n'` and `EOF` in the `getchar` loop instead of `'\n'` twice.

Comment: Also, I think an empty line will give wrong results (`a` will be `'\n` and a character will be lost reading `b`).

Comment: The inner `while` loop was definitely a mistake.  The 'empty line' condition is more interesting.  You're right that the behaviour is not great, but the `scanf()` would not return until some second character had been typed after the newline marking the end of the empty line.  If that second character was another another newline, then the 'gobble' loop would be a bad idea, but if there was some other character, that would be in `b` and there'd be one or more other characters to read before the end of the second line.  Hence the condition on `b` before entering the 'gobble' loop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sense of your `while` loop is wrong. Assume that `a` got the character `'y'`. Then, since `'y' != 'Y'` is true, you would continue to loop.

Here is a corrected loop.

```
    while ((a !='Y' && a !='y' && a !='N' && a!='n') || (b!='\n'))
    {
        if (b!='\n') ungetc(b, stdin),scanf("%*[^\n]%c", &b);
        a='n',b='\n';
        printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
        scanf("%c%c", &a,&b);
    }
```

Notice that the new code deals with the line too long, and drains the line for you, which was missing from your original code.

<kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHRSsNAEHy/r9hWmtyFKPqqTUHQh4JEESkUq7C33bYH8VKSVAltvz1eUtMWrM7TcDu7zMzR@ZyoOjOWktWUoZ8XU5NeLAaVsQV8oLEgP1MzVWItBDjQAjPAyLd@qCN/Yv2b5nmZOf1MdvtPCWPOwLZgp2vkSI4PrqGrdtqc0Dppj3rUDcHD0NNu0oxqfC1MwiAlQifyxz54HjS0PNB4Rzu1DQWbDUjdacwotT@z3rMaZnbQwMrOuSCpQ6jTWhW2joLX94l929nSP25b/M7cos0eBAEM49Htw/AO7uOX5zHUL/1Hm5Qgx4pzSDOQsUoBMwYk4mWBOuGjalqcrqidbsVxLISo6cnVgFFd018dZFysMgtXpw5x4j7t/73L471tVaHQgkSZi/Ib)</kbd>

---

```
while ((a !='Y' && a !='y' && a !='N' && a!='n') || (b!='\n'))
```

What we want `a` to be is one of `Y`, `y`, `N`, and `n`. If it is none of those things, enter the loop. Also, enter the loop if `b` is not the newline.

```
    if (b!='\n') ungetc(b, stdin),scanf("%*[^\n]%c", &b);
```

If `b` is not the newline, then likely the line was too long, so we have to drain the line. First, put the value of `b` back into the input stream. Then, tell `scanf` to scan past everything up to the newline character, and then consume it (into `b`).

```
    a='n',b='\n';
```

In preparation for the next `scanf` call to get the inputs, pre-populate `a` and `b` with values that will cause the loop to terminate. This is in case `scanf` jams (say on `EOF` or some file input error).

The rest of the code is as you had it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It's working but I don't understand the code

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while (  ( !( a =='Y' || a =='y')  &&  !( a =='N' || a =='n') )       ||      (  b !='\n') )
```

Comment: That seems to be a very complex condition.  Also, note that the question tests `b` against newline, `'\n'`, not `'n'` or `'N'`.